# Cant able to extend System Class (Address) in Apex

Tags: apex

```
public abstract class LAAddress extends Address{
}

public class LAAddress extends Address{
}
```

its giving me errors like

> Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended: System.Address

How can i extend Address class? Its supporting a return type in my @AuraEnabled code.

Answer (score 6):

You can't extend `Address`. Like the error message says, it's not virtual or abstract, so you just can't.

If your purpose is to pass it to a Lightning controller, then serialise it to a string using `JSON.serialize(myAddress)` and return that. Then deserialise in Javascript with `JSON.parse()`